# Understanding Syntax in Perl

Tags: perl

i may have a very simple question about understanding how the Syntax from Perl really works.

```
        unless ($alleles{$child}) {
            say (join "\t","line $.","no alleles in child") if $debug;
            next LINE;
```

What i want to achive is, that i no have more than 1 child in an array so i need to get rid of the $child and replace it with the array @children but there are some lines where i dont know if this would work aswell just changing the $child into an array 
So when i change it into an array does this really go through all the items of an array?

Comment: what i meant i that i need to check every single item of n array. i would use foreach but how do i change the $alleles{$child} part ?  thank you very much for your help

Comment: *" i need to get rid of the $child and replace it with the array @children"* Please give a [mcve] including how variables `%alleles`, `$child`, `@children` are defined. Currently there is too little information to understand what you want to do

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell what you want, but I think it's one of the following:

```
use List::Util qw( any );

# If $alleles{$_} is true for one or more element of @children
if ( any { $alleles{$_} } @children ) {
   ...
}
```

```
use List::Util qw( all );

# If $alleles{$_} is true for every element of @children
if ( all { $alleles{$_} } @children ) {
   ...
}
```

```
# If $alleles{$_} is true for more than one element of @children
if ( ( grep { $alleles{$_} } @children ) > 1 ) {
   ...
}
```